# Getting all of the request parameters in Python

Tags: python, mod-wsgi

This is a first step for my in `Python` on a `Linux` web-server using `mod-WSGI`.

I'm trying to get all of the `cell` parameters from the URL in a list like this:

```
...&cell=&cell=1&cell=2&cell=3&cell=4&cell=5&cell=6&cell=7&cell=8&...
```

So I started with code like this:

```
def application(environment, start_response):
    import cgi
    form = cgi.FieldStorage(fp = environment['wsgi.input'], environ = environment)
    temp_table_inputs=form.getlist('cell')
```

But I found that the first `cell` parameter is missing from the list (I presume because [getlist](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html?highlight=getlist#cgi.FieldStorage.getlist) removes it as the content is blank).

Two questions:

- How can I get a list including the blank values?
- How can I find which positions in the list are skipped by `getlist`?

*Note*: I know the `cell` stuff has a positional dependency but I'd rather look for a way to cope with that before naming the parameters according to their position (I inherited the code and quite a bit depends on the positional stuff, so renaming things will take a lot of effort).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html?highlight=getlist#using-the-cgi-module):

> The FieldStorage instance can be indexed like a Python dictionary. It allows membership testing with the in operator, and also supports the standard dictionary method keys() and the built-in function len(). Form fields containing empty strings are ignored and do not appear in the dictionary; to keep such values, provide a true value for the optional **keep_blank_values** keyword parameter when creating the FieldStorage instance.

Does it solve your problem?

Comment: I'm completely new to Python, so I'm trying to get a feel for the idioms used and which parameters to set where. So thanks for pointing me to `keep_blank_values`. Will try and let you know.

Comment: Don't worry :) I guess all you have to do is to change this line: `form = cgi.FieldStorage(fp = environment['wsgi.input'], environ = environment)` to `form = cgi.FieldStorage(fp = environment['wsgi.input'], environ = environment, keep_blank_values=True)`